# How to show data from database into a RecyclerView with high performance?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter

I wrote my own CursorAdapter for RecyclerView like following link: https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

Then I found whenever I change something in database and want to show it in RecyclerView, I need to create a new Cursor by db.query() and use CursorAdpater's changeCursor(). Since query() will scan all rows in database, the RecyclerView will refresh slowly when data amount is big even I insert only one row into database.

Besides, as we all know, RecyclerView provides notifyItemInserted/Removed(position) for developers so that the RecyclerView can refresh partly, which is useful and beneficial to memory/time. However, when I use CursorAdapter, I don't know when and how I can use these methods because changing cursor isn't adding something directly to dataset binding with RecyclerView but refreshing all items in fact.

So are there any better ways to show data from database in RecyclerView and use RecyclerView's improving method to show variety of database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can tell you what i've done...
A. Loaded a cursor using Loader.
B. Copied the cursor into arraylist that is attached to the adapter (the cursor isnt attached to the adapter directly), close the cursor. Works well if there isnt a lot of data - if there is a lot rows then i would have load some of it to the arraylist and then when the user would scroll down i would query again and load from the last row of the array.
C. When the user would like to delete or add something i would do the operation on arrayList first (*UI thread*) notifiyItemChanged and then change the db (*Back thread*)
Hope i helped.

Comment: I considered about the same thoughts as yours but they are not best methods. Firstly, CursorLoader is designed for refreshing data that may change at any time. In my situation, I know when to refresh data and UI so if I use CursorLoader, another thread will be created and thus waste resouces. Secondly, it seems easy to copy data from cursor to an arrayList but it has the same problem:memory waste because the arrayList isn't actually needed here----why should I use an arrayList if there is a cursor to provide data? Finally, Step C may cause error.

Comment: I'll start from the end, step c doesnt cause an error if done properly.
i've copied the array becuase i wanted to have 'swipe do delete' feature and i really really dont like todo any change to the DB on the main thread. Its maybe a 'waste' of memory (maybe) but its efficent with UI usage. Again, i think that another array here and there is a LOT cheaper then deleting a row in the DB on the UI.

Comment: I'm about to take your advice. But I thought about something new: load the cursor, copy data to an arrayList in Activity's onCreate() and bind it with RecyclerView.Adapter. Then when I want to change data on UI thread, I only update the arrayList. In the end, in Activity's onStop(), I will put all data of arrayList into database(insert new ones, update changed ones and maintain existed ones). Is it better?

Comment: The idea is good as long you are doing all of the heavy lifting on back threads.
a. onCreate() is called on the UI and copying data on it is nto a good idea.
b. use loaders, load the data to cursor and then copy it (on loadBackground() method at loader).
c. If u use the same data on the parent activity it will be an issue.

Comment: I think you are Chinese...OK, can you visit this website: http://www.zhihu.com/question/30579948 and see comments under first answer? I've asked a same question there and he gave me a different answer. Wish we can communicate more frequently.

Comment: He told me to write my cursorAdapter and use cursorLoader to load all data. I gave him this link to show your suggestions and he reminded me not to copy data from cursor to an array since it may cost a lot of time and make the application complicated. So the difference comes from "using cursorAdapter or not".

Comment: It all depends whether you have any remove/add to the adapter with animation. From my experience if you are trying to add/remove data with animation on adapter then you will change the data on the UI and with cursors its an issue. If you arent using any swipe2remove or something like that then CustoCursorAdapter for recycler will work ok.

Comment: Yes I'm going to implement "swipe-to-dismiss and undo" and something like that. So if I use arrayAdapter to add new data, I should execute add() of ArrayList in Adapter first on UI thread and execute insert() of DBHelper on another thread? Should I create a new thread?It seems that cursorLoader is used to do something when cursor is changed but here we don't need to get a new cursor by query().

Comment: Add to array on the UI and then DB on back thread as i said earlier.
No need for a new thread, use a threadpool for executers that will do all the back thread work for you so u will only use them and wont create new ones every time. No need to requery becuase the data is on the array that is displayed and the same as the on DB. U can requery everytime that the data changes from other place: server update example.

Comment: Got it. I'm going to try your methods. If I have problems, maybe I'll back. Anyway, thank you very very much!!!

Comment: You welcome, dont forgot to mark the answer as done.

Comment: Er..I don't have even only 15 reputation to accept your answer :(